# Bound on the number of signed sums of a non-zero vector that can all equal zero

Tags: linear-algebra, coding-theory

Let $u$ be a real vector of $m$ entries, and $A$ be a $\pm 1$ matrix of dimension $N\times m$, and real rank $\operatorname{rank}(A) = r$.

What are some conditions on $A$ (e.g. in terms of its rank $r$, or any other property of the rows of $A$) such that $u$ with $Au = 0$ is forced to have a zero entry?